# eval function doesnt turn dict-like string into dict?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, eval

So I have several strings in a DataFrame column looking like this one for example:

```
{'Free to Play': 17555, 'Multiplayer': 10499, 'FPS': 9248, 'Action': 8188, 'Shooter': 7857, 'Class-Based': 6098, 'Team-Based': 5363, 'Funny': 5155, 'First-Person': 4846, 'Trading': 4512, 'Cartoony': 4240, 'Competitive': 4116, 'Online Co-Op': 4016, 'Co-op': 3920, 'Robots': 3112, 'Comedy': 3049, 'Tactical': 2726, 'Crafting': 2491, 'Cartoon': 2450, 'Moddable': 2315}
```

I am trying to access the keys of the dict but as it is still a string I wanted to convert it into dictionaries and found people saying that eval can be used for that. And yes when I try like this it works fine and test_dict is of type dict:

```
test_str = "{'Early Access': 77, 'RPG': 202}"
test_dict = eval(test_str)
```

Yet when working with the strings in the DataFrame

```
tags = main_data["tags"]

for taglist in tags:
    taglist = "\"" + taglist + "\""
    tag_dict = eval(taglist)
```

tag_dict always remains a string and after some strings eval throws errors like these:

```
File "<string>", line 1
    "{'Action': 2681, 'FPS': 2048, 'Multiplayer': 1659, 'Shooter': 1420, 'Classic': 1344, 'Team-Based': 943, 'First-Person': 799, 'Competitive': 790, 'Tactical': 734, "1990's": 564, 'e-sports': 550, 'PvP': 480, 'Military': 367, 'Strategy': 329, 'Score Attack': 200, 'Survival': 192, 'Old School': 164, 'Assassin': 151, '1980s': 144, 'Violent': 40}"
                                                                                                                                                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I found out it might be a problem with the length of the strings as when using `taglist = "\"\"\"" + taglist + "\"\"\""` eval doesnt throw any errors, goes through all the strings but still they are not converted to a dict and remain str.

Maybe I have done some rookie mistake or there are better approaches to solving my problem?

Comment: the message shows the error, the string is not valid. it contains ` ... "1990's": 564 ...`

Comment: Try to remove the `"\""` around taglist.

Comment: Why did you add double-quotes to the string?  If it wasn't for the syntax error, `eval()`ing that would simply produce a string.

Comment: Why are you doing `"\"" + taglist + "\""`???

Comment: Look, the better approach is **don't try to use strings like this**. Why are they strings like this in the first place?

Comment: Why you use `taglist = "\"" + taglist + "\""`, is there any specific reason for this?

Comment: @JuanR oh yeah I didnt catch that Problem with the ' since the pointer was always pointing on an e or just outside of the string

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga its a project and they are from a CSV file we have to work with. Maybe I can make sure when reading it into the DataFrame they are read as dict and not string so this whole problem doesnt come up in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're serializing your dict to some kind of external storage, I would use json. It's designed for this, whereas eval is ... tricky. And you're actually running code, so whatever someone puts in the database, you're going to run it.

There's one catch. Json expects double quotes. Since it's already written to the database as python code with single quotes around the dictionary keys, you're going to have to convert those to double quotes to be legal json. I'd suggest fixing it once in the database, and then use json going forward.

```
import json

data_dict = {'Free to Play': 17555, 'Multiplayer': 10499, 'FPS': 9248, 'Action': 8188, 'Shooter': 7857, 'Class-Based': 6098, 'Team-Based': 5363, 'Funny': 5155, 'First-Person': 4846, 'Trading': 4512, 'Cartoony': 4240, 'Competitive': 4116, 'Online Co-Op': 4016, 'Co-op': 3920, 'Robots': 3112, 'Comedy': 3049, 'Tactical': 2726, 'Crafting': 2491, 'Cartoon': 2450, 'Moddable': 2315}
data_dict.update({'Early Access': 77, 'RPG': 202})
data_string = json.dumps(data_dict)

# write it to a file or database
# read it later, we'll assume that's data_string

data_dict = json.loads(data_string)
print (data_dict['RPG'])

database_string = "{'Free to Play': 17555, 'Multiplayer': 10499, 'FPS': 9248, 'Action': 8188, 'Shooter': 7857, 'Class-Based': 6098, 'Team-Based': 5363, 'Funny': 5155, 'First-Person': 4846, 'Trading': 4512, 'Cartoony': 4240, 'Competitive': 4116, 'Online Co-Op': 4016, 'Co-op': 3920, 'Robots': 3112, 'Comedy': 3049, 'Tactical': 2726, 'Crafting': 2491, 'Cartoon': 2450, 'Moddable': 2315}"

# this isn't a general purpose converter, but works for this case
# just to change the single quotes to double quotes
converted_to_legal_json = database_string.replace("'", '"')
data_dict = json.loads(converted_to_legal_json)
print (data_dict['Multiplayer'])
```

I can probably correct your eval if you want, but can't do it right this second. But like I said, not recommended. And I'd use ast.literal_eval rather than actually executing it with eval, for security reasons.